# Concatenate two numbers

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How do I concatenate two numbers in BigDecimal? I have this example:

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5);
        int a = 1;
        int b = 11;
```

and I want to concat `d.a` and `d.b` to generate `5.501` and `5.511` in `same length` without using divide or other operation!

Is there an instruction with BigDecimal to make it directly ?

Comment: Concatenation of anything except an empty string will change the length and, in any case, cannot be done without some other operation.  Who issued this homework and why is it so badly defined?

Comment: Is this homework? can a and b only have two digits, or any number of digits? What should be the result for an arbitrary number of digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the fact that `BigDecimal` can parse stings, and that strings are easy to concatenate.

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5);
int a = 1;
int b = 11;

BigDecimal da = new BigDecimal(String.format("%s%02d", d, a));
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(String.format("%s%02d", d, b));

System.out.println(da);
System.out.println(db);
```

**Output:**

```
5.501
5.511
```

The length is hard coded in `%02d`. You could generate the format string dynamically by inspecting `String.valueOf(a).length()`.

Comment: damn! you beat me to it! looks legit! :)

Comment: This doesn't work, see the edit in the question: //it can may be 5.777777777778888888..

Comment: So what is the expected behavior in that case?

Comment: @aioobe Good question. I assumed that a and b should be concatenated when the digits of d ended, but it's not actually well defined.

Answer (score 4):

```
da = d.add(new BigDecimal("0.00" + a);
db = d.add(new BigDecimal("0.0" + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either:

- convert them to strings, concatenate them and then return a new BigDecimal object
- divide a and b by 1000 and them add them to d

Comment: Except that he (for some strange reason) said *without using divide*.